# Why ingress rewrite not work in openshift?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I create a ingress by this example:

```
$ echo '
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: my.hostname.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /something(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: http-svc
            port: 
              number: 80
' | kubectl create -f -
```

But if I go to `my.hostname.com/something` the route is not matched, even if I changed it to

```
$ echo '
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: rewrite
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: my.hostname.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /something
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: http-svc
            port: 
              number: 80
' | kubectl create -f -
```

The route pass me to `http-svc` but the `rewrite` is not working.

So how can I do a complex rewrite which `haproxy.router.openshift.io/rewrite-target: /`  can not provide?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenShift routers aren't based on nginx, so nginx annotations/rules aren't going to do anything. If the [builtin HAProxy based functionality](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.11/networking/routes/route-configuration.html#nw-route-specific-annotations_route-configuration) doesn't meet your needs, you'd have to either [install an nginx based ingress controller](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-ingress-operator/blob/main/docs/nginx-ingress-controller.md) or handle the rewrite at the application level.

Comment: Thank you! For anyone looking, the rewrite target annotation for HAProxy is `haproxy.router.openshift.io/rewrite-target` which can be fouind in David's link above.